# how to exclude specific div inside a parent div

Tags: css

I wanna know how to apply style only into specific divs and not to all.
I mean every divs inside `<div class="parent">....</div>`must have some style except div with the `class="exception"`

```
 <div class="parent">
   <div class='one'>...</div>
   <div class='two'> ....</div>
   <div class="exception">..</div>
   <div class="one">....</div>
 </div>

div.parent:not('.exception'){
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

all the div inside div with class parent must have attribute `margin-top: 2em` except div with the class exception

Comment: just remove inverted comma (' ') from the class name, it should like this `div.parent div:not(.exception)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. But your selector means your style will take effect to `.parent` (`div class="parent">` element). Instead target child elements like this

```css
.parent > div:not(.exception) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class='one'>...</div>
  <div class='two'> ....</div>
  <div class="exception">..</div>
  <div class="one">....</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, but your selector should be: `div.parent div:not(.exception)`:

```css
div.parent > div:not(.exception) {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class='one'>...</div>
  <div class='two'> ....</div>
  <div class="exception">..</div>
  <div class="one">....</div>
</div>
```